# Rails 3 noob - difficulty populating an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

UPDATED WITH SOLUTION FROM BELOW PRODUCES NEW ERROR.

Users invite others to review their work. To track this, the invitations table has reviewer_id and reviewee_id fields. The model contains:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :users
```

To display all invitations for a user we first get all the invitations:

```
@invitations = Invitation.where("reviewee_id = ?", current_user.id ).select(:reviewer_id).order("updated_at")
```

Then we get all the users who were invited: (this part is wrong)

```
@reviewers = []
@invitations.each do |i|
  @reviewers << User.where("id = ?", i.reviewer_id )
end
```

This current solution produces the following:

```
undefined method `first_name' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I did a test with the following code to see what is in @reviewers:

```
<% @reviewers.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.id %><br>
<% end %>
```

Instead of returning the ids it returned:

```
2173491700
2173491200
2173490540
```

So the array is not getting populated appropriately.

I am grateful for your help and most grateful for specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to gather up all the IDs then pass them to `where`.

```
reviewer_ids = @invitations.collect { |i| i.reviewer_id }
@reviewers = User.where(:id => reviewer_ids)
```

This grabs all the reviewers in a single database call.

Comment: thanks! I am getting the following error, "Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id = 23,24,25)"

Comment: @Jay - You should do: `@reviewers = User.where(:id => reviewer_ids)`

Comment: No problem. Definitely go with what @mischa said re: `where` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to get the reviewers:

```
@reviewers = []
@invitations.each do |i|
  @reviewers << User.where("id = ?", i.reviewer_id )
end
```

The << adds elements to the array. And, before the iteration we create an array.

Comment: thanks. I am using your solution. The error i am getting is now part of my post.